# Excel: Use dynamic arrays with SUMIFS to generate a 2D output (based on 1D and 2D inputs)

Tags: arrays, excel, dynamic

I am looking to return a 2D dynamic array for SUMIFS, based on 1D and 2D input criteria. I have tried this successfully using BYCOL()/BYROW(), but this only returns 1D arrays by column or by row, whereas I want 2D (so just one formula gives me all the results).

I am trying to use the MAP() function to do this, but I am getting a wrong array size and #N/As. I have also tried combining BYROW() and BYCOL(), but this gives me a #CALC error and I don't think Excel supports this combination.

See below image where I have an example, where I am trying to sum up data for sub-totals by country. The numbers I want to get are at the bottom - but I have done this using cell-by-cell SUMIFS().

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems if you want to use Map you have to use arrays of the same size and shape. It's a bit of a pain, but you could do something like this just to prove a point:

```
=LET(range,D2:H6,
countries,B2:B6,
uniqueCountries,UNIQUE(countries),
cols,COLUMN(range),
nRows,ROWS(uniqueCountries),
nCols,COLUMNS(range),
seq,SEQUENCE(nRows,nCols),
HSTACK(uniqueCountries,MAP(IF(seq,uniqueCountries),IF(seq,cols),LAMBDA(a,b,SUM(range*(countries=a)*(cols=b))))))
)
```

[image]

So as you can see it's creating two arrays with three rows (the three unique countries) and five columns, the first array having one of the three countries copied across each row and the second one having one of the column numbers copied down each column. Then the two arrays are scanned and used to create the conditions for the 15 sums which are needed.

If you had a predefined list of different countries in say R2:R4 and only wanted the numbers, you could dispense with the hstack and the formula would be

```
=LET(data,D2:H6,
countries,B2:B6,
uniqueCountries,R2:R4,
cols,COLUMN(data),
nRows,ROWS(uniqueCountries),
nCols,COLUMNS(data),
seq,SEQUENCE(nRows,nCols),
MAP(IF(seq,uniqueCountries),IF(seq,cols),LAMBDA(a,b,SUM(data*(countries=a)*(cols=b))))
```

)

Comment: Thank you very much Tom - very helpful. I am certainly not set on using MAP() as the solution, I just thought given how that function works it was perhaps the best way. I do like your solution - but ideally the output array would be only the numbers and not include the country names. That way, if there are multiple datasets we can still use the same function but only have one set of country names (rather than having to repeat every single data set)

Comment: You're welcome. It would be easy to remove the Hstack and take the list of country names from a common range rather than using Unique to get them from the dataset each time.

Answer (score 0):

A `non-volatile` set-up would be less straightforward, though for starters you could consider:

`=LET(α,D2:H6,β,B2:B6,γ,SORT(UNIQUE(β)),HSTACK(γ,SUMIFS(OFFSET(INDEX(α,,1),,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(α),0)),β,γ)))`

If you don't have access to `HSTACK` then I can provide an alternative.

In the meantime I'll try to find a non-volatile set-up.

Comment: Thank you for this Jos - I have access to HSTACK() but would prefer not to use OFFSET(). I wonder if I can use HSTACK() combined with BYCOL()...